# Get resource file inside the application

Tags: vb.net

i was wondering if i could access a folder inside the Resources folder of the application?
i would make it to eliminate the use of the debug directory in storing files and to use the clickonce deployment.

I need your advices and suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change where the project outputs it's build to. Right click on the Project's name and click properties then go to Build and down near the bottom it tells you where it will output the build to. If you're building it in debug, it usually goes to bin\Debug, release goes to \bin\Release, etc.

You can look [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm) for information on the ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: i still got the same message..when i deploy the program i want to include the folder where i had put all my images...

Comment: oh, when you make the setup, just tell it to include that folder